# Compare two arrays with one condition and display data from both arrays in one

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

Array1

```
array (size=51)
  0 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => int 1
      'title' => 
        array (size=1)
          'fr' => string '95% des intégrateurs écrivent mal leurs titre' (length=47)
      'slug' => string '95-des-integrateurs-ecrivent-mal-leurs-titre' (length=44)
      'date' => string '2017-05-16 00:00:00' (length=19)
      'introduction' => 
        array (size=1)
          'fr' => string 'Incidunt qui quod aut blanditiis velit. Aperiam eligendi et enim molestiae esse quidem. Rerum ex suscipit et rerum dolor dicta fugit. Omnis cumque libero quaerat autem aut voluptas ea. Pariatur praesentium id quia nisi quae esse incidunt et. Maxime laboriosam ex enim repellat dolorem aperiam.' (length=293)
      'content' => 
        array (size=1)
          'fr' => string '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla ornare arcu sapien, sit amet porttitor tortor laoreet ut. Ut accumsan augue lectus, ac auctor lorem hendrerit id. Maecenas suscipit consectetur velit, eu posuere nisl viverra a. Pellentesque vel justo scelerisque tortor vulputate consequat. Vivamus quis placerat libero. Maecenas facilisis erat at magna cursus, ac interdum nisl dictum. Sed eros arcu, lacinia ut commodo non, condimentum vitae odio. Sed at ex justo. Mauris id arcu semper, gravid'... (length=4050)
      'image' => string 'http://ecoleinfographie.app/uploads/articles/da2186c4b43385f6b7ba8100b054d7be.jpg' (length=81)
      'status' => string 'PUBLIÉ' (length=7)
      'category_id' => int 13
      'author_id' => null
      'teacher_id' => int 36
      'created_at' => string '2017-05-16 15:28:02' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2017-05-29 12:36:21' (length=19)
      'deleted_at' => null
      'orientation' => string 'web' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=15)
      'id' => int 2
      'title' => …
      .....
```

Array2 :

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string '/blog/95-des-integrateurs-ecrivent-mal-leurs-titre' (length=50)
      'pageTitle' => string '95% des intégrateurs écrivent mal leurs titre' (length=47)
      'pageViews' => int 7
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string '/blog/creer-un-paysage-vectoriel' (length=32)
      'pageTitle' => string 'Créer un paysage vectoriel' (length=27)
      'pageViews' => int 3
  2 => 
    array (size=3)
      'url' => string '/blog/perferendis-expedita-et-ea-sint-repellendus-veritatis-quae-voluptas-eos' (length=77)
      'pageTitle' => string 'Perferendis expedita et ea sint repellendus veritatis quae voluptas eos.' (length=72)
      'pageViews' => int 3
  3 =>
```

I would like to compare all basename(array2['pageTitle']) with array1['slug'] and for each element matched, I would like to create a new array with all elements contains in each. So, the result should be is :

```
array3
  'id' => int 1
  'title => …
  'slug' => 'my-cool-title'
  'date' => …
  'introduction' => …
  ..........
  'url' => string '/blog/95-des-integrateurs-ecrivent-mal-leurs-titre'
  'pageTitle' => string 'Créer un paysage vectoriel' (length=27)
  'pageViews' => int 3
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Thank you !

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Start writing code.

Comment: @u_mulder I've already searched, a lot. I start in PHP, so I do not know everything. I do not know where to start. Failing to provide me with the code, do you have any leads to give me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP,
 you could do something like this.

```
foreach($array2 as $a2){

    foreach($array1['data'] as $a1){

        if($a2['pageTitle'] == $a1['slug']){

           <!-- 
            populate array3 here with the data from array1 and arra2 
           -->

        }
    }
}
```